# How do I activate Screen Mirroring on a Samsung Galaxy S5 running Marshmallow?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-s-5, screen-sharing, miracast, amazon-fire-tv

I have an Amazon Fire TV stick, and I'd like to mirror my Samsung Galaxy S5's display to it.

**It works fine with my old Galaxy S4** (just tried it right now), but I cannot get it to work with my Galaxy S5: The "Screen Mirroring" option just does not seem to be available anywhere on the phone.

It's a non-rooted Samsung Galaxy S5 with the latest OTA update (Marshmallow) installed.

---

**What I've tried:** I already googled for `s5 marshmallow screen mirroring missing` and tried the following recommendations:

- Pull down the notification shade, click <kbd>Edit</kbd> and activate the Screen Mirroring option. On my device, *there is no such option*.
- Click "Quick Connect" on the notification shade and register the TV stick as a TV device. Tried that, but the only option I have is to *"Share content"*. It does not offer to share my screen.

Here are two a screen shots as proof. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious...

[image: screenshot of the quick access icons]
[image: screenshot of the Quick Connect screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not mention this in your question, but your screenshot shows that you are using the Galaxy S5 **Neo**.

Unfortunately, that's one of the subtle differences between the Galaxy S5 and the Galaxy S5 Neo: On the Neo, Samsung silently dropped support for the screen mirroring feature.

I could not find any official sources for this, but there seems to be consensus in the community that screen mirroring (MiraCast) is just not available on the Neo <sub>([Source 1](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s5/639682-galaxy-s5-neo-where-app-screen-mirroring.html), [Source 2: German, see Community Question section](http://www.samsung.com/at/support/model/SM-G903FZKAATO))</sub>.

If you check the [list of MiraCast certified devices](http://www.wi-fi.org/product-finder-results?sort_by=default&sort_order=desc&capabilities=2&keywords=SM-G900F,SM-G903F), you will notice that the S5 (SM-G900F) is listed, but the S5 Neo (SM-903F) is not.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you want Mira cast it does come enabled on the s5 neo stock Canadian version anyway and if not your always able to install custom Roms like both lineage os 15.1 and 14.1 works flawless with Mira cast even had a controller hooked up playing games lol
Samsung put a chipset capable of it just didn't enable them in some countries or os's it seems